# Accessing class that added scrollview as a sub view and some other questions

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm working on an iOS app. Basically, one section of my app has a large scrollview with 6 other scrollviews added as sub views (using the method [scrollView addSubview:object.view]) so that it pages between 6 different scrollviews. Each scrollview has some textviews that I need to save the contents of.
In each sub scrollview, I added an inputAccessoryView to the keyboard to add a Done button, and I want to call a method to save the data when this button is pressed, and then remove the keyboard (the latter of which I already have done, I just need to figure out the saving part).
I feel that it would be easier to have one method in my 'super' scrollview that will save all of the data so I can just add in a few lines of code to each sub scrollview (by the way, these sub scrollviews aren't subclassed from the main scrollview, they are UIViewController subclasses, so I can't just use super) because I have to copy/paste it into 6 different files. I was able to access the 'super' class (the big scrollview that has all of the others in it) by importing it in the 'sub' scrollview and creating a new object, but I feel that's not what I'm supposed to do. That leads me into my next question.
If access the bigger scrollview in this way, trying to access the text property of the UITextViews returns null, whereas accessing the same property from within the class of the sub scrollview displays the text.

Please let me know if I'm doing something completely wrong, as I feel like having 6 different scrollviews is really inefficient (but testing it on two iPod touches, a 2nd gen and a 4th gen, there isn't much lag at all so it can't be too inefficient or else it'd hog memory and make it lag, right?)

Thanks,
Lee

EDIT:
I'm still having trouble with this. The button I created was created programmatically, so I can't link it to the first responder in Interface Builder. Is there a way to do this programmatically as well? Here's my code to create the inputAccessoryView:

```
-(void)createInputAccessoryView{
inputAccView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 40.0)];
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 40.0)];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBttn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(endEdit:)];
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:doneBttn]];
[inputAccView addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
[doneBttn release];
}
```

The button points to a method (in the same class) that will close the keyboard. However, before I close the keyboard, I need it to call another method to save the data (which is in a different class). Does this help anyone's understanding?

Comment: I would advise you to reduce the size of this question and try to break it up into multiple questions and/or reorganize it. Nobody wants to sift through a wall of text and try to imagine what it is your are doing.

Answer (score 0):

When posting a question, *show* your code.  Don't just *describe* your code.  It's much easier for us to help you when we can see what you're talking about without the filter of what you think is important.

Nevertheless, I think I know what you are doing wrong and how to help you.  You said this:

> I was able to access the 'super' class (the big scrollview that has all of the others in it) by importing it in the 'sub' scrollview and creating a new object ... trying to access the text property of the UITextViews returns null

It sounds like you have put this in your child scrollview:

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {
    ParentScrollView *parent = [[ParentScrollView alloc] init];
    [parent saveEverything];
}
```

and then you expected this newly-created parent scroll view to be hooked up to your existing text views.  But why would it be connected?  When you load a view hierarchy from a nib, the nib loader takes care of making the connections that you established using Interface Builder.  But if you create views in code, you have to establish the connections yourself, and you didn't.

You shouldn't be creating a new parent scroll view anyway.  You need to send a message to the *existing* parent scroll view.  There are a few ways you could do that.  In this case I recommend using the responder chain.

You can read about the responder chain in [*Cocoa Application Competencies for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html).  Here are the important concepts for this problem:

- When a text view is active, the text view is the first responder in the chain.
- Each ancestor view of that text view is in the chain.

You can hook up a button to send an event up the responder chain when the button is touched:

- In Interface Builder, you just connect the button to the "First Responder" placeholder (in the upper-left area of the window).  You need to have already defined the `IBAction` in your source code for it to show up when you connect the button to the First Responder placeholder.
- In code, you use `nil` as the target parameter of `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`, like this:

  ```
  [self.saveButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(saveEverything:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  ```

If you hook your button up that way, UIKit will take care of searching the responder chain for the first responder that responds to the `saveEverything:` message.  In your case, that should be your (existing) parent scroll view.

One more thing: the parent scroll view isn't really the right place to put your save code.  In the MVC design pattern, a controller is more appropriate.  Lucky for you, if a view has a `UIViewController` associated with it, the `UIViewController` is *also* in the responder chain.  So you can put your `saveEverything:` method on your view controller instead of your parent scroll view.

Comment: Thanks for the information, it helped me understand what I did wrong. A few things though. I can't connect the button in IB because I create it programmatically (since it's on an inputAccessoryView). Also, I don't really have a view controller either. I started my project as view based, but I changed it later on to be tab based (I went into the mainWindow.xib and removed the view controller, and added a tab bar), so my old viewcontroller class is the view containing my parent scroll view.
Could I create a controller just for data saving purposes? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: One thing I just realized while reading through your post again. I don't really want to set the method to save everything to the Done button, I'd rather call the save everything method from within another method because it has to remove the keyboard as the first responder.
If there's a specific area of my code you would like to see, just ask and I'll post it.